# Returning data using Task

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task

I want this function to return a result:

```
public Task<Item_DataColl> invoke_command_READ(string UCPTName)
{
    Item_DataColl res =  await Task.FromResult(thread_command_READ_result(UCPTName));
    return res;
}
```

I don't understand how `Task` works and how I can use it to make thread with a result. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: Short version: instead of `Task.FromResult(...)`, use `Task.Run(() => thread_command_READ_result(UCPTName));`. Note that you'll need to add `async` to your `invoke_command_Read()` method declaration if you want to use `await` in the method. Long version: you need to study the documentation and other references which explain how you can use the Task Parallel Library to execute operations in the background (which, by default, will use the thread pool to execute those operations in a separate thread).

Comment: If you get to a point where you've got a question that _hasn't_ already been answered umpteen times on Stack Overflow already, and/or which is already adequately addressed by the documentation, please post a new question, including a good [mcve] and a detailed explanation of what _specifically_ you are having trouble understanding or figuring out.

Comment: Yes, i forgot the async on the declaration, i erased it before post this, don't know why.
I'm on the documentation from a long time and if i ask on stack, it's because i'm not able to perform even a simple task return.
By the way, i don't think that an edit to add or delete some spaces is a good edit...

Comment: _"i don't think that an edit to add or delete some spaces is a good edit"_ -- it is when the original author of the post (i.e. you) did not bother to format the code in a clean, readable way. FWIW, I'm not actually the one who changed the whitespace...someone else did, and I used the "Accept and Edit" option in the review queue to fix the other problems in your original post (like spelling and grammar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular case, it's best to make the method `async`, like so:

```
public async Task<Item_DataColl> invoke_command_READ(string UCPTName)
{
   return await thread_command_READ_result(UCPTName);
}
```

If, however, you want to return task, but NOT async (why??), you can do this:

```
public Task<Item_DataColl> invoke_command_READ(string UCPTName)
{
    Item_DataColl res =  await Task.FromResult(thread_command_READ_result(UCPTName));
    return Task.FromResult(res);
}
```

You can think of `Task<T>` as a wrapper for `Thread` that will run until the `Func` passed to task returns a result (or, in case of `Task`, returns control).

Comment: The async was forgotten.

However, i've tried your first thing yesterday, and it doesn't work. I'm not able to find out why this problem occured. As now, it work fine, thanks

Comment: @NFrb i made an edit, take a look again.